# Loop through element and attribute of SimpleXmlElement in Php

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<info id="12AB" conf="D4XD">
<cinfo code="CB">Consumer Business</cinfo>
<cinfo code="EB">Enterprise Business</cinfo>
</info>
```

How do I loop through the cinfo elements, that I can read value, i.e. Consumer Business and attribute value, i.e. CB ?

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);
    foreach ($obj->children() as $cinfos) {
?????



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://codepad.org/RumbRhoS) should do it:

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($obj->cinfo as $cinfos) {
    // This is the value
    $val = $cinfos[0];
    echo $val."\r\n";;
    // Iterate through the attributes
    foreach($cinfos[0]->attributes() as $key => $val) {
        echo $key,'="',$val,"\"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the line `$val = $cinfos[0];` here - `$cinfos` is already a single element from the `foreach` loop. The text content is extracted by converting to a string, e.g. `$val = (string)$cinfo;` or implicitly in `echo $cinfo;`. Similarly, `foreach($cinfos->attributes()...` not `foreach($cinfos[0]->attributes()...`.